# Can't see anything on the Xamarin ListView (DataBinding - MVVM)

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, mvvm

I tried to use some DataBindings on the listview but nothing is listed.

**Model.cs**

```
public class Post
{
    // Columns inside of the Database table

    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(250)]
    public string Experience { get; set; }
}
```

**MainViewModel.cs**

```
private ObservableCollection<Post> _postList;
public  ObservableCollection<Post> PostList
{
    get { return _postList; }
    set { SetProperty(ref _postList, value); }
}

public void ReadDataBase()
{
    using (SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(App.DatabaseLocation))
    {
        conn.CreateTable<Post>();
        var postList = conn.Table<Post>().ToList();
        PostList = new ObservableCollection<Post>(postList);
    }
}
```

**HistoryPage.xaml**

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:viewModel ="clr-namespace:TravelRecordApp.ViewModel"
             x:Class="TravelRecordApp.View.HistoryPage">

    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <viewModel:MainViewModel/>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <ListView x:Name="postListView" ItemsSource="{Binding PostList}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextCell Text="{Binding Experience}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</ContentPage>
```

**HistoryPage.xaml.cs**

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();
    MainViewModel mv = new MainViewModel();
    mv.ReadDataBase();
}
```

Notes:

After debugging I confirmed that whenever I go to the HistoryPage, the PostList is updated with the new data. So SQL Data reading and page navigation is working fine. I just can not see the contents from the ListView.

I tried also using just `List<Post>` before `ObservableCollection`, the result is the same.

Answer (score 0):

the problem in your code is that your xaml is binding to an instance that is different then the one your calling ReadDataBase() function from.
try please my solution please:

```
private ObservableCollection<Post> _postList;
public  ObservableCollection<Post> PostList
{
    get { return _postList; }
    set { _postList =value; }
}
```

remove the <ContentPage.BindingContext> from xaml;

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:viewModel ="clr-namespace:TravelRecordApp.ViewModel"
             x:Class="TravelRecordApp.View.HistoryPage">
  <ContentPage.Content>
    <ListView x:Name="postListView" ItemsSource="{Binding PostList}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextCell Text="{Binding Experience}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
  </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

in the code behind

```
private MainViewModel viewModel;
public HistoryPage() // constructor 
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            viewModel = new MainViewModel();
            this.BindingContext = viewModel;
        }
protected override void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();
    viewModel.ReadDataBase();
}
```

Comment: I can not bind PostList if I remove the <ContentPage.BindingContext> part. It says "No DataContext found for Binding PostList" (Rebuilding and relaunching is done)

Comment: this.BindingContext = viewModel; are you writing this in the conductor ?

Comment: put your xaml between   <ContentPage.Content>. i edited my code check it. @noob123

Comment: Yes I put that line on the constructor. And as far as I know, <ContentPage.Content> is the default property for the ContentPage, so it did not make any change.

Comment: are you adding InitializeComponent();  @noob123

Answer (score 0):

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();

            using (SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(App.DatabaseLocation))
            {
                conn.CreateTable<Post>();
                var posts = conn.Table<Post>().ToList();
                postListView.ItemsSource = posts;
            }
                
        }
I think you can assign the ItemSource after reading the database. so not in the xaml
```

This is my Historypage.xaml.cs

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).